# TinyMCE adds styles on save

Tags: javascript, styles, tinymce, rte

Hello:
I'm using tinyMCE, copying from word and dropping the text into the editor. When I save it once it works as it should and gives me this formating:

```
<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin: 0in 0in 10pt;"><span style="line-height: 115%; color: #0f243e; font-size: 12pt; mso-ascii-font-family: Calibri; mso-ascii-theme-font: minor-latin; mso-hansi-font-family: Calibri; mso-hansi-theme-font: minor-latin; mso-themecolor: text2; mso-themeshade: 128;"><span style="font-family: Calibri;">Course Description:</span></span></p>
```

But when I go to the same page, and hit save again, I get this code

```
<span style="line-height: 18px;">

<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; line-height: normal; mso-outline-level: 2;"><strong><span style="font-size: 13.5pt; font-family: &quot;Cambria&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;; mso-fareast-font-family: &quot;Times New Roman&quot;; mso-bidi-font-family: Arial; color: #4f81bd;">Course Description:</span></strong><strong><span style="font-size: 18.0pt; font-family: &quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;; mso-fareast-font-family: &quot;Times New Roman&quot;; color: #7d7d7d;"></span></strong></p>
```

Comment: please describe exactly what you do and what your tinymce configuration looks like!

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing extra formatting because you are pasting from MS Word.  Use the clear formatting option in Word or use a plain text editor, such as notepad, that won't add any extra formatting when you paste.

Answer (score -1):

for me,I had same issue, my add post had

```
$_POST = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_POST );
```

my edit page did not, I added it and it was fine. so compare your add & edit pages, the may differ.

Comment: how is this not useful?
I had exact same issue and easily resolved with adding this 1 line?

Why search through looking for questions to try and help on when you loose points????

Don't worry, I won't try and help anymore.